# @Bindable doesn't generate field in BR class

Tags: android, android-databinding

I started studying Data binding recently.
This problem occurred in my source code:

```
public class MyClassName extends BaseObservable {    
    @Bindable
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name <Can\'t find name in BR>);
    }
}
```

As I know:

> The Bindable annotation should be applied to any getter accessor method of an Observable class. Bindable will generate a field in the BR class to identify the field that has changed.

But when I added the `@Bindable` annotation for field `name`, I can't find `BR.name` in the setter method.

My project contains two packages: `com.example.package1` and `com.example.packag2`. Above code is in `com.example.packge2`.

But when I added the `@Bindable` annotation I can't import `com.example.package2.BR`, Android Studio suggested `com.example.package1.BR` only.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: You misspelled `package2` twice differently in this question. Maybe you also misspelled it in your source code and that's why your IDE or compiler can't find it?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the generated sources need to be generated first -
and they won't be generated, while there are unknown references present.
This is indeed kind of self-defeating, but that's the way it is.

a) Just comment out this line:

```
// notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
```

b) build the project

c) then un-comment it again.

Comment: I modified the post. Could you check new description ?

Answer (score -1):

Option 1:

Just `clean` the project then `Rebuild` the Project.

Option 2:

Try with `Invalidate caches and restart` in android studio.

At last IF this both are not working then

Just use `BR.variableName` it will show `error` on screen but at `runtime` you will not see any `error`.Just make sure that `variable Name` and `BR.NAME` must be same.

Comment: I modified the post. Could you check new description ?

Comment: just remove all BR library . here `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.variable);`  press `alt+Enter` it will import respected  package